# SSAS Cube characters not showing properly

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssas-2008

I have a ssas cube with a customer dimension that displays special characters (chinese..etc).  These characters do not show up properly when I bring the associated attribute in Excel. In the dimension table the info type is stored as char. I also changed the collation of both dimension and attribute but this did not help. Creating a language translation did not help as well. What should I do?

Comment: If you browse the cube in SSMS/BIDS, do the characters show up properly?  If so, you likely need to change the encoding on the connection string Excel is using to draw data from the cube.

Comment: Nope, it does not.  I also tried the locale identifier thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CHAR in the database won't work for UNICODE strings.  Chinese characters usually involve using the upper end of the codepage (multi-byte characters).  You need NCHAR/NVARCHAR.